# automatic scrolling using animation in css

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm new to animation. I want to implement bottom to top automatic scrolling of the images. Here I have written some code.

index.html :

```css
#container {
  height: 350px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.photobanner {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  top: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  animation: bannermove 10s linear infinite;
}
.photobanner:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

.photobanner img {
  margin: 0 0.5em;
}

@keyframes bannermove {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  }
}
```

```html
 <div id="container">
                <div class="photobanner">
                  <img
                    src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xckZy.jpg"
                    alt=""
                    style="height: 285px; width: 100%"
                  />
                  <p>image1</p>
                  <img
                    src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTiml.jpg"
                    alt=""
                    style="height: 285px; width: 100%"
                  />
                  <p>Image2</p>
                  <img
                  src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTiml.jpg"
                    alt=""
                    style="height: 285px; width: 100%"
                  />
                  <p>Image3</p>
                  <img
                   src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTiml.jpg"
                    alt=""
                    style="height: 285px; width: 100%"
                  />
                  <p>Image4</p>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Above code does automatic scrolling. but it displays only first 3 images. If i update

```
   @keyframes bannermove 
   {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
   }
  100% {
   transform: translate(0%, -100%); //-50% to -100%
 }
 }
```

it displays all the images , but after displaying all the images it creates some empty space. I don't understand how to fix this..Please help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could start off making the child elements of the banner the same height as the container.

So, you translate the photo banner by -50%. You will want to translate it by the full height of the photo banner minus the height of the container. Now duplicate the last child element, that will make the animation reset, without you being able to notice.